# How to run glm code over different subsets within dataframe & create new column with the extracted values?

Tags: r, dplyr, glm

I have this piece of code that runs a glm, which is used to generate the "midpoint" of a subject's responses [coded as trochiac/iambic, 0 or 1] to a list of numeric stimuli, saves the midpoint as a value and prints the value in the console.

```
glm.1 <- glm(coderesponse~stimulus, family = binomial(link="logit"), data=data)
midpoint <- -glm.1$coefficients[1]/glm.1$coefficients[2]
cat(sprintf("file : %s\nmidpoint : %.2f",datafile,midpoint))
```

At the moment, this code runs over the entire dataframe. I was wondering how to modify this code so that I could run it over various subgroups within my main dataframe and create a new column with those values for each subgroup?

e.g. for each subject, I would like to generate the midpoint value for each block (1-8) within each stimtype "bd", "nm" and "nm". That midpoint value would be the new value in the  newly created column for all the rows for each block within each stimtype.

We also eventually want to aggregate the values of each block to be reduced to one row containing the midpoint value (rather than keeping all of the rows with the same value).

a small dummy version of my main dataframe (only includes one subject and stimuli up to 6):

```
subject <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
stimulus <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
block <- c(3, 3, 3, 7, 7, 7, 4, 4, 4, 8, 8, 8, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 6, 6, 6, 3, 3, 3, 7, 7, 7, 4, 4, 4, 8, 8, 8, 2, 2, 2, 6, 6, 6)
blockprocedure <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
stimtype <- c('bd', 'nd', 'nm', 'bd', 'nd', 'nm', 'bd', 'nd', 'nm', 'bd', 'nd', 'nm', 'bd', 'nd', 'nm', 'bd', 'nd', 'nm', 'bd', 'nd', 'nm', 'bd', 'nd', 'nm', 'bd', 'nd', 'nm', 'bd', 'nd', 'nm', 'bd', 'nd', 'nm', 'bd', 'nd', 'nm', 'bd', 'nd', 'nm', 'bd', 'nd', 'nm')
blocktype <- c('mouth', 'mouth', 'mouth', 'nose', 'nose', 'nose', 'mouth', 'mouth', 'mouth', 'nose', 'nose', 'nose', 'mouth', 'mouth', 'mouth', 'nose', 'nose', 'nose', 'mouth', 'mouth', 'mouth', 'nose', 'nose', 'nose', 'mouth', 'mouth', 'mouth', 'nose', 'nose', 'nose', 'mouth', 'mouth', 'mouth', 'nose', 'nose', 'nose', 'mouth', 'mouth', 'mouth', 'nose', 'nose', 'nose')
coderesponse <- c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1)

dummy = data.frame(subject, stimulus, block, stimtype, blockprocedure, blocktype, coderesponse)
```

I initially tried, but obviously it's not the way to go...:

```
dummy <- data %>% 
  group_by(subject, stimtype, block)
dummy$test <- NA

glm.1 <- glm(coderesponse~stimulus, family = binomial(link="logit"), data=dummy)
midpoint <- -glm.1$coefficients[1]/glm.1$coefficients[2]
dummy$test <- midpoint
```

I'm quite new to coding, so I hope this all makes sense!
Thank you for any help/insight!

Comment: `group_split` instead of `group_by` may be what you are looking for?

Comment: hello! I tried using group_split, but it created a list of tibbles of which I wasn't able to run the glm code over? I'm not quite sure what is happening!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a good place to use the combiation of `tidyr::nest` and `purrr::map`.

Indeed, as `?nest` says, "Nesting is often useful for creating per group models".

Here is some code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

get_midpoint = function(data){
  glm.1 = glm(coderesponse~stimulus, family = binomial(link="logit"), data=data)
  rtn = -glm.1$coefficients[1]/glm.1$coefficients[2]
  rtn
}

dummy %>% 
  nest(data=-c(subject, stimtype, block)) %>%
  mutate(midpoint=map_dbl(data, get_midpoint))
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 30 x 5
>    subject block stimtype data             midpoint
>      <dbl> <dbl> <fct>    <list>              <dbl>
>  1       1     3 bd       <tibble [2 x 4]> -1.69e11
>  2       1     3 nd       <tibble [2 x 4]> -1.69e11
>  3       1     3 nm       <tibble [2 x 4]> -1.69e11
>  4       1     7 bd       <tibble [2 x 4]>  3.00e 0
>  5       1     7 nd       <tibble [2 x 4]> -1.69e11
>  6       1     7 nm       <tibble [2 x 4]> -1.69e11
>  7       1     4 bd       <tibble [2 x 4]>  4.00e 0
>  8       1     4 nd       <tibble [2 x 4]>  4.00e 0
>  9       1     4 nm       <tibble [2 x 4]> -1.96e11
> 10       1     8 bd       <tibble [2 x 4]>  4.00e 0
> ```

Here, you can `nest` all columns but `c(subject, stimtype, block)` in a column named `data`. Then you can `map` around this column to apply a custom function. As your function returns a double, I used `map_dbl`.

#### EDIT

You could also use summarise:

```
dummy %>% 
  group_by(subject, stimtype, block) %>% 
  summarise(midpoint = get_midpoint(tibble(coderesponse, stimulus)))
```

This outputs the same result (in different order though).

Comment: Nice! I was trying some combinations of `summarise()`, and `group_map()`, e.g. `summarise(midpoint = group_map()`. Do you think this could work with some tweaks?

Comment: @KJM yup, see my edit :-) However the `tibble` call make this way less scalable. If you decide to change your function formula to `stimulus~blocktype+blockprocedure`, you will have to change your code at several places.

Comment: Awesome. I agree with you - your original code is tidier, but still it’s good to learn other methods. This is something I love about SO. Thanks for the edit

Comment: that's the spirit!

Comment: Thank you so much, this gave me just the right result! I was wondering if it were possible to unnest the rest of the columns or if it's better (or possible to) create a new dataframe using this code and then combine the midpoint value column generated from the new dataframe to my main dataframe?

Comment: @LizJu Glad I helped :-) Yes, it is possible, you should check the `unnest` function in the `tidyr` package. Whether it is better or not is up to you, as your result will be of length 30 if nested but 42 if unnested.